# Python Perform action on all list elements and include only some in output using List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following function that works fine:

```
output = []
for a, b in itertools.product(
    list_a, list_b
):
    x= perform_action(a,b)

    if b.relevant:
        output.append(x)

return output
```

How can I rewrite this using list comprehension - if possible ?

In short what I'm looking for is to `perform_action` for all items and include only the relevant ones in the output.

Reproducible example:

```
from itertools import product
a = [2,3,4]
b = ["a","b"]

def foo(p,r):
  out = "{0}---{1}".format(p,r)
  print(out)
  return out

li = [foo(p,r) for p,r in product(a,b) if p>3]

print(li)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell--does `perform_action` mutate `b.relevant`? If not, just `[perform_action(a, b) for a, b in itertools.product(list_a, list_b) if b.relevant]` might work?

Comment: You just add an `if` conditional on the end, as in `fish_list = [fish for fish in fish_tuple if fish != 'octopus']` which I got from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) example.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use list comprehensions for side-effects. A comprehension usually corresponds to a ``map`` transformation, whereas a ``for``-loop corresponds to an imperative action.

Comment: Note that adding an ``if b.relevant`` to the list comprehension will *not* run ``perform_action(a,b)`` for this ``b``. Is that desirable?

Comment: no, that's the whole point. I want perform_action to run regardless of b.relevant. I want that flag just to control the final list content

Comment: Well, you can do that, but it involves quite some workarounds. Basically you have to split the original stream, apply ``perform_action`` action to one and keep ``b`` of the other, *then* filter the unwanted elements. *Why* do you want to do all this? What do you want to gain by using a list comprehension?

Comment: `perform_action` having a side effect (mutating `b.relevant`) might be the underlying problem and sounds like you _may_ have a brittle design. If you always need to `perform_action`, then it probably makes more sense to do it in two steps from a readability/logical standpoint, assuming efficiency isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! The reason for this is just that I don't like `output = []`  and `output.append(..)`. `b.relevant` is not linked to `perform_action`

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a list comprehension *only* for side effects. I don't think this is any worse than having a function with side effects in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you feel about two layers of list comprehension?

```
return [x for  b, x in [(b, perform_action(a,b)) for a,b in itertools.product(l_a, l_b)] if b.relevant]
```

I know you didn't come here for code readability advice, but, don't turn this into a list comprehension, it's far less readable as one. If you're thinking of memory efficiency, just do a generator.

Comment: The inner comprehension can be turned into a generator expression to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi what would that look like? do you just unwrap the `[]` on the inner comprehension?

Comment: `return [x for b, x in ((...) for a, b in product(...)) if b.relevant]`

Comment: wow, I would have assumed that just made a tuple, TIL. Thanks @chepner

Comment: No, tuples (with the exception of the empty tuple) are created by commas; the parentheses are only needed to prevent the comma from being interpreted as something else. (E.g., a two-argument function call `f(1,2)` vs a one-argument function call `f((1,2))`.)